# Java HtmlUnit click on anchor link does not work. How do I get the new page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to click on a "More" anchor tag on a website using HtmlUnit in order to expand a list until the more anchor tag does not exist.

```
page = client.getPage(url);

HtmlAnchor anchor;

while((anchor = page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@class='load-more list']")) != null) {

page = (HtmlPage) anchor.getPage();

}
```

I've also tried `page = anchor.click();`

`System.out.println(anchor)` shows

> HtmlAnchor[ a
>   href="/guideitem/list/?id=g407&requestType=browse&filter=ZmlsdGVyPXMlM2FmcmVlJmxpbWl0PTMw"
>   class="load-more list" data-hijax="false" ]

I will continue to look into this problem and post what I find here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a somewhat similar problem, hope this helps. 
It "solved itself" after we disabled CSS on the WebClient:

```
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
```

My anchor was:

```
<div class="my-anchors-parent-class"/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0) class="text" id="buttonSearch" style="display: block;">Search</a>
</div>
```

It had some JQuery attaching the .click() handler to it, who acted based on the 'class' property of my anchor's parent:

```
    $('.my-anchor's-parent-class').each(function () {
        $(this).children('a').click(function () {
          // if parent has another given class appended, call .myFunction(this)
          // else, call other function
        });
    });
```

When we reenable the CSS, the .click() is broken again.